# PHP Composer - php-sql-query-builder

Tags: php, sql, composer-php

I just figured out how to install and use PHP composer and used it to instal [php-sql-query-builder](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder/issues) to my project. The system created the vendor folder, etc. however I am having issues using classes within the package. It gives me the following error, any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder' not found in D:\Documents\CadetPortal\php\lib\login.class.php on line 15
```

**Login.class.php**

```
    require_once ("core.class.php");
    require_once ("../../vendor/autoload.php");

    use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder;

    class LoginSystem {
        private $core;
        private $builder;
        private $config;

        function __construct(){
            $this->core = new coreFunctions();
            $this->builder = new GenericBuilder();
            $this->config = require('core.config.php');
        }
//....
    }
```

**EDIT**

**fncregister.php**

```
require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";
$LoginManager = new \ThomasSmyth\LoginSystem();

echo $LoginManager->Register($_POST["StrSurname"], $_POST["StrForename"], $_POST["StrEmail"], $_POST["StrPassword"], $_POST["DteDoB"], $_POST["StrGender"], $_POST["StrToken"]);
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "nilportugues/sql-query-builder": "^1.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ThomasSmyth\\": "php/lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class source files shouldn't have any `require_once` statements at all in them. Follow the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) spec for naming. Put your classes in a namespace to avoid collision with other classes you might include via composer. Then put one class in one file, named the same as the class. For example, the LoginSystem class should be in a file named LoginSystem.php.

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class LoginSystem
{
    ...
}
```

Then set your `composer.json` to point your namespace to your source directory:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Now, your main app invoker or front controller should be the only place that includes the autoloader:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$login = new \MyNamespace\LoginSystem();
...
```

Comment: Is the directory relative to the autoloader? I added the namespace `ThomasSmyth\Core` and `ThomasSmyth\Login` and added the directory `php/lib/` to them in the composer.json file, does that seem ok?
 https://gyazo.com/47ccb152af8ff7e09c9588ab1f951c77

Comment: The directory is relative to the location of the composer.json file. So if you have a class ThomasSmyth\Core and it's in the file php/lib/Core.php, then you want `"ThomasSmyth\\": "php/lib/"`. I.e., classes in the ThomasSmyth namespace can be found in the php/lib/ directory.

Comment: Should you always use double \ in the namespace in the composer.json? Furthermore, the SQL Query Builder uses `NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder`, so would the directory for this be to the folder the GenericBuilder is in or just to the vendor package `NilPortugues`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You generally only need to use double slash when the slash is right before a quote, otherwise it's interpreted as an escape character for the quote. But it's not harmful to always use it. You don't need to explicitly specify the directory for any external packages you use, because they're already specified in their own composer.json files. Just make sure you have `nilportugues/sql-query-builder` listed in your require section, and the autoloader will find it.

Comment: Ok, one last question. You said "your main app invoker or front controller should be the only place that includes the autoloader". If I wish to call a class that requires another class, for example, my Login Class requires my PDO DB Class, do you mean I require the PDO class in the file that requires the Login Class or can I leave it in the constructor function of the Login Class?

Comment: You just include the package name in the require section of the composer.json and that's it. Then any class anywhere can simply instantiate any other class in any other namespace, and the autoloader will find it. The only place you should ever use `require_once` in your code is the top-level entry point, like index.php.

Comment: Note, if you have a package with a really long namespace layout like `NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder` then you may optionally put a `use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder;` at the top of your Login class. This is not required, it's simply an alias that allows you to type `new GenericBuilder()` instead of `new \NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder()` later in the class.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have worked. Thanks a lot for the help! You've been able to explain namespaces in simple enough terms for me to get my head around, which other documentation hasn't been able to do.

Comment: Great! Good luck!

Comment: Actually I lied. It doesn't seem to find the class as I get this error: `fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ThomasSmyth\LoginSystem' not found in D:\Documents\CadetPortal\php\functions\fncregister.php on line <i>4</i>`. Any suggestions? I've updated my main question with the code snippets. phpStorm is showing no error, it's only when WAMP runs it.

Comment: What is the name and location of the file that LoginClass is defined in?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6c6cdeaeff83cbc4e9a8a84e3c8ba515 It's the LoginSystem.php

Comment: You'll need `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";` in any top-level entry point. So if you're not using a front controller and requests are going directly to `php/register.php` then you'll need it there too.

Comment: fncregister.php is a file called via an AJAX request, so it would be the top level file surely and that has the `require_once` to the autoloader.

Comment: Make sure LoginSystem.php has a top level namespace declaration at the top: `namespace ThomasSmyth; class LoginSystem { ... }`

Comment: It has `namespace ThomasSmyth; class LoginSystem {...}` at the top.

Comment: It's odd. PHPStorm is not flagging any issue, however, WAMP is when I actually test the code.